# compojure destructuring making integers... not integers?

Tags: clojure, key, compojure, datomic

This Compojure GET route with hard-coded id...

```
   ;posts 
(GET "/post:id" [id :as request]
  ;(str "the post id is... " id)
   (def email (get-in request [:session :ze-auth-email]))
   (vb/post-page-draw email 17592186045616))
```

Works^

However, with symbolic id (on the last line)...

```
   ;posts 
(GET "/post:id" [id :as request]
  ;(str "the post id is... " id)
   (def email (get-in request [:session :ze-auth-email]))
   (vb/post-page-draw email id)
```

Where the url is:

```
localhost:4000/post17592186045616  ;;i.e. the number from above
```

(edit: no colon between the word post and the id)

Returns a huuuge stack trace, mainly breaking on

```
java.lang.Exception
processing rule: (q__7967 ?title ?content ?tags ?eid), 
message: processing clause: [?eid post/title ?title], 
message: Cannot resolve key: 17592186045616
```

So, I've been able to isolate it to compojure destructuring just not liking the integer I'm passing... how can I get my *(vb/post-page-draw email id)* to work with parameters passed via the URL?

Comment: `id` is returned as a string you need to convert it to a number (using `Long/parseString` for example) and you should not nest `def`, use a `let` instead. `def` is global, not local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```clj
(vb/post-page-draw email (Long. id))
```

Comment: Cool idea... but I get back the following: java.lang.NumberFormatException
For input string: "17592186045617"

Comment: got it.  you were on the right track for sure.  solved it with (Long/valueOf id)

Comment: Ohh! It was a Long! Maybe this is works and is shorter `Long.`